# Python Reportlab ecc200datamatrix barcode type. cannot generate due no attribute found

Tags: python, barcode, reportlab

Trying to generate a barcode in Ecc200 Datamatrix format but cannot do it. Getting error message - Object has No attribute 'x' Can some help or offer advise on what to do?

```
   from reportlab.graphics.barcode import ecc200datamatrix
   from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate,Paragraph
   from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

   pdf=SimpleDocTemplate("Barcodetest.pdf")
   flow_obj=[]
   styles=getSampleStyleSheet()
   codetext="V:1.1:44591-01;SERIAL:IQP22143;dfd:xxxxxxxxxx;MODEL:xxxx;;"
   code=ecc200datamatrix.ECC200DataMatrix(codetext)
   flow_obj.append(code)
   pdf.build(flow_obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this was asked two years ago but ran into the same problem today trying to add a datamatrix barcode to a PDF generated via reportlab.  So I decided to take a quick look into it.

The draw method references the object's x and y attributes.  But those attributes aren't defined or referenced anywhere else within the code.  Maybe those attributes were factored out years ago from a base object and they were missed in this code.  Who knows.

You can manually set the object's x and y attributes to 0 and the output it generates is a readable barcode.

```
from reportlab.graphics.barcode import ecc200datamatrix
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate,Paragraph
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet

pdf=SimpleDocTemplate("Barcodetest.pdf")
flow_obj=[]
styles=getSampleStyleSheet()
codetext="V:1.1:44591-01;SERIAL:IQP22143;dfd:xxxxxxxxxx;MODEL:xxxx;;"
code=ecc200datamatrix.ECC200DataMatrix(codetext)
code.x = code.y = 0
flow_obj.append(code)
pdf.build(flow_obj)
```